# Need more information on console based UI using Perl Curses::UI, TUI etc

Tags: perl, templates, tui

I am looking for developing a console based UI, I see Perl Curses::UI, Text based TUI as possible options. Roughly, I need the admin to select [ from known options ] and enter the mkfs and mount options in this UI and then actual mount the FS.

I'm looking for a UI
- which will be easier and popular to develop and test
- there is some DTL available for loading the Widgets from a template file (XML/html etc.)

Any more information and pointers and experiences will help.
thanks,
-Vikrant

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at my [`Tickit`](http://metacpan.org/module/Tickit) distribution, also.

It is based on high-level widgets, as with many of the GUI systems.

There is also some ongoing work via [`Tickit::Builder`](http://metacpan.org/module/Tickit%3a%3aBuilder) to be able to load UI definitions dynamically from description files, perhaps stored in XML/YAML/JSON/etc...